# Excel HH:MM Adding Up Doesn't Work

Tags: excel

I have several **TO** and **FROM** columns (one for each day) with data as follows

```
09:00   17:00   08:00   12:00   09:00   17:00   08:00   12:00   09:00   17:00   08:00   12:00   08:00   12:00
```

At the end I do the following formula just in case someone puts text in

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(C6-B6),C6-B6,0)+IF(ISNUMBER(E6-D6),E6-D6,0)+IF(ISNUMBER(G6-F6),G6-F6,0)+IF(ISNUMBER(I6-H6),I6-H6,0)+IF(ISNUMBER(K6-J6),K6-J6,0)+IF(ISNUMBER(M6-L6),M6-L6,0)+IF(ISNUMBER(O6-N6),O6-N6,0)
```

All cells are formatted as **HH:MM**

At the end, I get a very odd answer of 16 hours. So I tried to do it day by day. When I get to the 4th day (H and I), it starts getting wierd

```
IF(ISNUMBER(C6-B6),C6-B6,0) - answer of 8
IF(ISNUMBER(C6-B6),C6-B6,0)+IF(ISNUMBER(E6-D6),E6-D6,0) - answer of 12
=IF(ISNUMBER(C6-B6),C6-B6,0)+IF(ISNUMBER(E6-D6),E6-D6,0)+IF(ISNUMBER(G6-F6),G6-F6,0) - answer of 20
=IF(ISNUMBER(C6-B6),C6-B6,0)+IF(ISNUMBER(E6-D6),E6-D6,0)+IF(ISNUMBER(G6-F6),G6-F6,0)+IF(ISNUMBER(I6-H6),I6-H6,0) - answer of zero
```

So in columns Q to W, I do the following

```
Q - IF(ISNUMBER(C6-B6),C6-B6,0)
R - IF(ISNUMBER(E6-D6),E6-D6,0)
S - IF(ISNUMBER(G6-F6),G6-F6,0)
T - IF(ISNUMBER(I6-H6),I6-H6,0)
U - IF(ISNUMBER(K6-J6),K6-J6,0)
V - IF(ISNUMBER(M6-L6),M6-L6,0)
W - IF(ISNUMBER(O6-N6),O6-N6,0)
```

Columns **T/U/V/W** were showing decimals but after changing them to **HH:MM**, they showed the right values. In **Column P** I did the following

```
=SUM(Q6:W6)
```

However I only get an answer of **16**

Can anyone shed any light on what's happening? I presume because it's going over the 24 hour time period?!?

Answer (score 2):

I had to change the cell format to `[hh]:mm`